# Не работает подключение mysqli_connect()

Tags: php

```
    function cf(){
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","ARTEM","la03rip","futt");
    return $connect;
}

    if($connect==true){
        echo 'работает';
    }
```

Comment: Так вы не вызвали функцию подключения `$connect = cf();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо банальной опечатки с вызовом функции, в этом коде действительно не хватает важного пункта - настройки mysqli таким образом, чтобы она сама сообщала о своих проблемах. И также необходимо устанавливать кодировку соединения. Для UTF-8 это будет utf8mb4. Правильно будет соединяться, как написано [здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect):

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","ARTEM","la03rip","futt");
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8mb4");
```

Кроме того, писать код соединения в такую функцию в принципе неправильно. Функции предназначены для повторного использования. А если эту функцию вызывать несколько раз, то она создаст несколько одновременных содинений с БД, и просто убьет сервер.

Надо хотя бы использовать статическую переменную:

```
function cf(){
    static $connect;
    if (!$connect) {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","ARTEM","la03rip","futt");
        mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8mb4");
    }
    return $connect;
}
```

теперь эту функцию можно вызывать сколько угодно раз. и она будет возвращать одно, единожды установленное соединение

```
$connect = cf();
if($connect){
    echo 'работает';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вы пока в самом начале изучения PHP (и вероятно программирования вообще). Не спешите запускать всё подряд, что найдёте в интернете. Разбирайте примеры очень внимательно и добивайтесь полного понимания того, что делает каждая строчка.

В вашем примере вы определили функцию. Но не вызвали её. Так же вы не поняли идеи области видимости переменной. Чтобы разобраться с этим, начните изучение PHP с чтения [справочника](http://php.net/manual/ru/langref.php) официальной документации. Читая, пробуйте реализовать примеры. Не перескакивайте сразу на сложные темы, понимание основ очень важно.